# Anonymous functions in Informix?

Tags: database, plsql, database-connection, informix, spl

I would like to know how anonymous functions are written in IBM Informix , I mean in Oracle we can write an anonymous pl/SQL block function which is not a stored function, this implies a function that is not created in database and cannot permanently exist in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Succinctly, there are no such things as anonymous functions in Informix.  SPL exists only inside functions.  There isn't a way to store an arbitrary block of SQL except as a (named) function.

Comment: thank you Mr.Leffler , I would like to know one more thing from you i.e, is it possible to include sql query into a unix shell script and unload query output to shell variable?

Comment: You can use DB-Access if you don't mind it's somewhat noisy output.  However, I wrote `sqlcmd` about 20 years ago because I regard DB-Access as too noisy.  You can get it from the software archive at the IIUG (http://www.iiug.org/software).